# Change select value based on column_type in information_schema

Tags: mysql

Alright, I'm going to make this quick.  Below I have a select showing me all the column_names that have a `tinyint` data_type.  With the data it returns below, I need to write an enclosing query selecting from `my_table` and change the output of the `SELECT` data, I suspect by using `CASE` when a `tinyint` is `0` to No, and `1` to Yes.

```
    SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAME
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        table_name = 'my_table'
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'tinyint'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query in a sample:

```
create table a ( i tinyint, b char(5));

SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAME,
        case  DATA_TYPE 
        when 'tinyint' then 'Yes' 
                       else 'No' 
        end    
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        table_name = 'a';
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca71a/9/0)

**EDITED** because OP has lost the faith.

Hi bigman, Belive me you don't want! Ok ... welcome to dark side of dynamic sql:

```
create table a ( i tinyint, b char(5));
insert into a values (1,'si'),(0,'no');
SELECT @a := 
        concat( 
          'select ', 
          group_concat( 
            case  DATA_TYPE 
            when 'tinyint' then concat(
                                 'if( '       ,
                                 COLUMN_NAME           ,
                                 ' = 0, \'No\', \'Yes\' )'
                                )
                           else COLUMN_NAME            
            end                      
          ),
          ' from ',
          table_name ,
          ';'
        )
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        table_name = 'a';    
PREPARE stmt FROM @a;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[Results](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e473/3/3)

```
| IF( I = 0, 'NO', 'YES' ) |  B |
---------------------------------
|                      Yes | si |
|                       No | no |
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.  This is helpful, very much so but not quite what I am looking for.  I still want to return the row normally, but any columns that are `tinyint`, change those to yes/no depending on the value.

Comment: Hard to understand for me due to bizarre use of relational database, please post samples and expected data.

Comment: ya, tell me about it.  Believe me, im a convention whore, this stuff drives me crazy.

`SELECT * FROM my_table`, let's say it returns 4 columns, id, name, bool_column, second_bool_column.  The return values would be `(1, 'some name', 0, 1)`  but what I would need is `(1, 'some name', 'No', 'Yes')`, though this table has far more columns than 4.

Comment: perhaps you can use `find_in_set( bool_column, 'No', 'Yes' )` . This seems the easiest solution. I don't know a static method to achieve results as you want.